# How to make Scicos show its menus in ScicosLab on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MATE?

Tags: 16.04, unity, fonts, mate

I'm using [ScicosLab](http://scicoslab.org/) for a long time since Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It was working very well without issues.

Currently I tried to install it into my clean Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS MATE by downloading two needed packages and installing them into system:

```
wget http://cermics.enpc.fr/~jpc/scilab-gtk-tiddly/files/ubuntu/tkdnd1_1.0-1_amd64.trusty.deb
wget http://cermics.enpc.fr/~jpc/scilab-gtk-tiddly/files/ubuntu/scicoslab-gtk_4.4.1-1_amd64.trusty.deb
sudo apt-get install ./tkdnd1_1.0-1_amd64.trusty.deb ./scicoslab-gtk_4.4.1-1_amd64.trusty.deb
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi
```

and installation finishes without issues (so all dependencies were satisfied). My system does not have any obsolete and/or locally installed packages (only two above).

When I launch it with `scicoslab` it starts normally. But when I try to run `scicos` from its console I get window with blind menus:

[image: scicos with blind menus]

In ScicosLab console it shows the following warning:

> (scilex:20046): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkAccelLabel to a GtkMenuItem, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkMenuItem can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkAccelLabel

I'm not sure are they critical to show menus.

Is it fonts issue? How can I debug this?

Note: on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Unity Scicos shows menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some non-trivial comparison between Unity and MATE VMs I have found the problem - it was *Topmenu GTK+* module.

So we need to change desktop file to remove `topmenu-gtk-module` from `GTK_MODULES` variable:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /usr/share/applications/scicoslab.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ScicosLab
Comment=Scientific Computing using ScicosLab
TryExec=/usr/bin/scicoslab
Exec=env GTK_MODULES="canberra-gtk-module" /usr/bin/scicoslab
Icon=/usr/lib/scicoslab-gtk-4.4.1/config/puffin-gtk48.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Education;Science;Math;
StartupNotify=false
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.15

EOF
```

and then we can use Scicos as before:

[image: Scicos on 16.04 LTS MATE]

Note: this method is not needed for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE, but here we need atfirst to download `libreadline6` package manually (with `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/readline6/libreadline6_6.3-8ubuntu8_amd64.deb`) and install it with `sudo apt-get install ./libreadline6_6.3-8ubuntu8_amd64.deb`) and then install ScicosLab packages.